# Syntax error: WITH is not valid input in this position

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression

So I have this similar request

```
    WITH customers_in_usa AS (
        SELECT 
           customerName, state
        FROM
           customers
        WHERE
           country = 'USA'
    ) SELECT 
        customerName
    FROM
        customers_in_usa
    WHERE
        state = 'CA'
    ORDER BY customerName;
```

But when wrote it I caught an error: 'WITH is not valid input in this position' [error_picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3xfO.jpg). Can you help me to understand what's wrong in this code?

Answer (score 7):

`WITH customers_in_usa AS` is for now invalid MySQL code.
MySQL will support CTE's in the future in MySQL version 8..

You could rewrite your SQL code, that should give the same results.

```
SELECT 
    customerName
  , state
FROM 
   customers 
WHERE
   country = 'USA'
 AND
   state = 'CA'
ORDER BY
   customerName
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL doesn't support [common table expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) and `WITH` syntax until version 8.0.1.

Version 8.0 is still not production-ready as I write this (but it's in Release Candidate status, so it'll be GA pretty soon).

---

Update: MySQL 8.0 released its first GA version 8.0.11 on 2018-04-19.