# MySQL: access inner select table alias in another inner select

Tags: mysql, sql

I saw some related posts any try to modify the examples to work for my case but couldn't do it.

I have 3 tables: `A`, `B` and `C` which contain milions of records.

I want to be able to:

1. Filter some of the records of `A` table.
2. Then, on the filtered table, filter it again by joining it with `B` table based on shared column in both tables.
3. Then, on the filtered table filter it even more by joining it with `C` table based on shared column in both tables
4. Count the amount of records on `c` table.

What I tried is:

```
select count(*) from 
    (select  A.exmp_column from A where A.insert_date BETWEEN '2018-03-28 00:10:38' and '2018-03-29 00:10:38') as a,

    (select * from B where a.shared_column = B.shared_column) as b,

    (select * from C where b.shared_column = C.shared_column) as c;
```

But it seems like I can't use the alias `a` and `b` inside the inner selects.. How can I achieve what I need?

Sorry if my terminology is incorrect, I'm new to `SQL`.
Thanks

Comment: You can use `CTEs` for each of your requirement and then combine `CTEs` and get the count by joining `CTEs`.

Comment: Please elaborate, if you can.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
select count(*) 
from A
inner join B on A.shared_column = B.shared_column
inner join C on B.shared_column = C.shared_column
where A.insert_date BETWEEN '2018-03-28 00:10:38' and '2018-03-29 00:10:38'
```

Comment: No. for performance reason, I need to begin by filtering A by date and only on the filtered records - join B and C, and not the other way around. Could it be done?

Comment: If you think the order you write the query is the order sql server implements it, you are mistaken. If you want to control the flow to achieve performance, you'll have to use query hints. This is not an easy thing to do, and can hardly be used advantageously by someone with few experience.

Answer (score 0):

As explained earlier, you can use CTEs for each of your requirement and then combine CTEs and get the count by joining CTEs:

```
;WITH cte_a AS
(select  A.exmp_column 
FROM A 
WHERE A.insert_date BETWEEN '2018-03-28 00:10:38' and '2018-03-29 00:10:38')
, cte_b AS
(select * 
FROM B 
WHERE a.shared_column = B.shared_column)
, cte_c AS
(select * 
FROM C 
WHERE b.shared_column = C.shared_column)
SELECT COUNT(c.*)
FROM cte_a a JOIN cte_b b ON a.shared_column = b.shared_column
JOIN cte_c c ON c.shared_column = b.shared_column
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it gives my syntax error: `with is not valid input at this position` can this be related to the fact I'm using mySql cluster 7.4? Is there an alternative?

Comment: Try adding `;` before with since it needs to be in the first position while execution.

Comment: Are you using mysql? `CTEs` are not supported by `mysql`.

Comment: Yes, I am, sorry for the confusion. Is there a workaround?

Comment: I believe then you can use above approach suggested by @George. Also you can refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410422/syntax-error-with-is-not-valid-input-in-this-position