# How to get consecutive records have same value in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a table like below, how can I get all records have same account_id, ordered by begin_date, and consecutive records have same value

```
begin_date       value    account_id   other
20180701    1013        222         11
20180702    1013        222         11
20180701    1022        222         12
20180702    1022        222         12
20180703    1023        222         12
20180701    1024        111         13
20180702    1024        111         13
```

In this case, following should be returned:

```
begin_date       value    account_id   other
20180701    1013        222         11
20180702    1013        222         11
20180701    1022        222         12
20180702    1022        222         12
20180701    1024        111         13
20180702    1024        111         13
```

I have tried to use key word "WITH", but looks like [it is not valid anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410422/syntax-error-with-is-not-valid-input-in-this-position), this is what I wrote:

```
WITH Ordered AS (
            SELECT *,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY account_id, begin_date, value) AS order_id
            FROM addresses)
SELECT o1.account_id, o1.value
FROM Ordered o1
    INNER JOIN Ordered o2 ON o2.account_id == o1.account_id AND o2.value = o1.value AND s2.order_id = s1.order_id + 1
UNION
SELECT o2.account_id, o2.value 
FROM Ordered o1
    INNER JOIN Ordered o2 ON o2.account_id == o1.account_id AND o2.value = o1.value AND s2.order_id = s1.order_id + 1
order by
        1,2;
```

Comment: show us your query. `WITH` is valid on mysql only on v8+

Comment: explain the logic. why 20180703 is removed?

Comment: thanks, updated. 20180703 's value 1023 which is not the same with previous 20180702's value

Comment: Again explain the logic and show us what error you have.

Comment: @user8142520 . . . Please define "consecutive records".  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering unless a column specifies that ordering.  No such ordering column is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

this one should work for you

```
select
    x.*
from
    <table_name> as x
    join (  select
                value,
                account_id,
                other
            from
                <table_name>
            group by
                value,
                account_id,
                other
            having
                count(*) > 1) as y on   x.value = y.value
                                        and x.account_id = y.account_id
                                        and x.other = y.other
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `lead()` and `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             lag(value) over (partition by account_id, other order by begin_date) as prev_value,
             lead(value) over (partition by account_id, other order by begin_date) as next_value
      from t
     ) t
where value in (prev_value, next_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your MySQL server version is below 8, try this:

```
select a.*
from data a
where exists(
  select *
  from data b
  where b.account_id = a.account_id and
        b.value = a.value and
        b.begin_date in (a.begin_date + interval 1 day,
                         a.begin_date - interval 1 day)
);
```

**Output:**

```
| begin_date | value | account_id | other |
+------------+-------+------------+-------+
| 2018-07-01 |  1013 |        222 |    11 |
| 2018-07-02 |  1013 |        222 |    11 |
| 2018-07-01 |  1022 |        222 |    12 |
| 2018-07-02 |  1022 |        222 |    12 |
| 2018-07-01 |  1024 |        111 |    13 |
| 2018-07-02 |  1024 |        111 |    13 |
```

Test it online with [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be893e/1).