# Getting syntax error for WITH RECURSIVE (MySQL 8.0.27 version)

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression

I keep getting a syntax error "WITH is not valid input in this position" for WITH RECURSIVE. I've seen a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410422/syntax-error-with-is-not-valid-input-in-this-position), where people back in 2018 said MySQL will support CTE's in MySQL version 8. Some other sources also refer that CTE should work for MySQL since version 8.0. My current version is 8.0.27, however, I still can't use WITH RECURSIVE in MySQL Workbench.

The query I need to retrieve the family tree is:

```
  WITH RECURSIVE family_path (individual_id, first_name, path) AS
(
  SELECT individual_id, first_name, first_name as path
    FROM individual
    WHERE parent IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.individual_id, c.first_name, CONCAT(fp.path, ' > ', c.first_name)
    FROM family_path AS fp JOIN individual AS c
      ON fp.individual_id = c.parent
)
SELECT * FROM family_path
ORDER BY path;
```

Is there any way for me to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL Server 8.0? You can check with `SELECT VERSION();` It doesn't matter if you're using MySQL Workbench 8.0, that's just the client. The SQL language support depends on the server.

Comment: I tested your SQL query on my instance of MySQL Server 8.0 Server, and it has no syntax error. It complained that I don't have a table named `individual` but that's expected, and it shows that it got past the syntax validation without error.

Comment: Ooh, now I see, my version is 5.6.50... Thanks! Do you by a chance know how to upgrade the version from 5.6 to 8? All the ways I found so far look overcomplicated...

Comment: You're right, it's a big job to upgrade a major version of any software. Welcome to being a professional software developer! :-) I don't mean to be flippant. It requires careful testing and patience. I agree it's not easy. I think you've probably already found the documentation on the process of upgrades. For example: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading.html